# Handling ONNX/ML.NET models with generic interfaces

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-core, ml.net, onnx

i'm kind of struggling with a ML.NET related problem here and am hoping that someone might can help me.

I'm developing an (.NET core) application which consumes ONNX models whose inputs are unknown at compile time. What I've done so far:

I'm able to compile an assembly during runtime which contains the input class definition and load this definition:

```
        var genericSampleAssembly =
            AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath("/app/storage/sample.dll");
        Type genericInputClass = genericSampleAssembly.GetType("GenericInterface.sample");
```

Also I'm able to train a model with that dynamically created Inputtype using Reflection:

```
        MethodInfo genericCreateTextLoader = typeof(TextLoaderSaverCatalog).GetMethods()
            .Where(_ => _.Name == "CreateTextLoader")
            .Single(_ => _.GetParameters().Length == 6)
            .MakeGenericMethod(_genericInputClass);

        TextLoader reader = genericCreateTextLoader.Invoke(_mlContext.Data, new object[] { _mlContext.Data, false, ',', true, true, false}) as TextLoader;

        IDataView trainingDataView = reader.Read("sample.txt");
        var debug = trainingDataView.Preview();

        var pipeline = _mlContext.Transforms.Concatenate("Features", _featureNamesModel
            .AppendCacheCheckpoint(_mlContext)
            .Append(_mlContext.Regression.Trainers.StochasticDualCoordinateAscent(labelColumn: "Label",
                featureColumn: "Features")));

        ITransformer model = pipeline.Fit(trainingDataView);
```

But I'm not able to make predictions by now because I don't know how to invoke the PredictionEngine. I'm able to get a generic version of that CreatePredictionEngine method but don't now how to cast that returning object to an PredictionEngine and finally invoke the Predict method:

```
        MethodInfo genericCreatePredictionEngineMethod = typeof(PredictionEngineExtensions).GetMethods()
            .Single(_ => _.Name == "CreatePredictionEngine")
            .MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { genericInputClass, typeof(GenericPrediction)});

        var predictionEngine = genericCreatePredictionEngineMethod.Invoke(_model, new object[] {_model, _mlContext, null, null});
```

`predictionEngine` is of Type object in this case but I need to cast it to something like `PredictionEngine<genericInputClass, GenericPrediction>`, while `genericInputClass` is the class from that dynamically created assembly and `GenericPrediction` is a simple class with one output I know at compile time.

So whats missing is something like:

```
        MethodInfo genericCreatePredictionEngineMethod = typeof(PredictionEngineExtensions).GetMethods()
            .Single(_ => _.Name == "CreatePredictionEngine")
            .MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { genericInputClass, typeof(GenericPrediction)});

        PredictionEngine<genericInputClass, GenericPrediction> predictionEngine = genericCreatePredictionEngineMethod.Invoke(_model, new object[] {_model, _mlContext, null, null}) as PredictionEngine<genericInputClass, GenericPrediction>;

        float prediction = predictionEngine.Predict(genericInputClass inputValue);
```

Does anyone had a similar problem or has any other hints?

I might missed some lines, because I copy/pasted and simplified it pretty quick. In case something is missing, I'll provide it later.

EDIT: I constructed a minimal example to show the basic problem. As mentioned in the comments `dynamic` isn't possible due to the ML.NET methods.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Loader;


namespace ReflectionSample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Example with a known Type
            var extendedClass = new DummyExtendedClass();
            SampleGenericClass<String> sampleGenericClass = extendedClass.SampleGenericExtensionMethod<String>();
            sampleGenericClass.SampleMethod("");

            // At compile time unknown Type - In reality the loaded dll is compiled during runtime
            var runtimeCompiledSampleAssembly =
                AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath("C:/Program Files (x86)/Reference Assemblies/Microsoft/Framework/.NETCore/v4.5/System.IO.dll");
            var compileTimeUnknownClass = runtimeCompiledSampleAssembly.GetType("System.IO.TextReader");

            var reflectedExtensionMethod = typeof(Extensions).GetMethods()
                .Single(_=>_.Name== "SampleGenericExtensionMethod")
                .MakeGenericMethod(new[] {compileTimeUnknownClass});

            var howToCastThis = reflectedExtensionMethod.Invoke(extendedClass, new object[] {extendedClass});

            // whats missing:
            // howToCastThis is of Type object but should be SampleGenericClass<System.IO.TextReader>
            // I need to be able to call howToCastThis.SampleMethod(new System.IO.TextReader)
            // I thought this might work via reflecting SampleMethod and MakeGenericMethod

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public sealed class SampleGenericClass<T>
    {
        public void SampleMethod(T typeInput)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Invoking method worked! T is of type {typeof(T)}");
        }
    }

    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static SampleGenericClass<T> SampleGenericExtensionMethod<T>(this DummyExtendedClass extendedClass)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Invoking extension method worked! T is of type {typeof(T)}");
            return new SampleGenericClass<T>();
        }
    }

    public class DummyExtendedClass
    {
        public DummyExtendedClass() { }
    }
}
```

Greetings
Sven

Comment: The issue here appears to be about reflection in a deep object model with extensive generics. ML.NET just happens to be the stage on which this is playing out. Please create a [mcve] to make it easier for someone to help you. You might even figure out a solution in the process.

Comment: Yes, thats true, the main problem has nothing to do with the framework but the framework is the reason that other possible solutions like `dynamic` are not working so I thought I'll use this example for "the bigger picture". But I think, I'll reach out to more people with a more generic example so I'll try to provide it later.

Comment: Unfortunately, lack of familiarity with this particular library is making it difficult for me to keep track of what you're trying to do. I know what to do, just not how to apply it, since I can't reproduce the starting point on my end.

Comment: I updated the post with a minimal example, you might need to modify the path to the sample dll. Any help solving this is very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice job on the MCVE.  I was able to invoke `SampleMethod`; it turns out there's not much to it and it's probably less complicated than you imagined.

In your example, the object you're getting, `howToCastThis`, is of a type that's already close-constructed.  As long as you start from that instance's type, you don't need to use `MakeGenericMethod`.

Let's say you have an object instance, `compileTimeTypeUnknownInstance`, for the parameter you want to pass to `SampleMethod`.  Since `System.IO.TextReader` is abstract, `compileTimeTypeUnknownInstance` would have to be of a concrete, `TextReader`-derived type.  With those conditions satisfied, the following works:

```
var sampleMethod = howToCastThis.GetType().GetMethods()
    .Single(mi => mi.Name == "SampleMethod");

sampleMethod.Invoke(howToCastThis, new object[] { compileTimeTypeUnknownInstance });
```

`SampleMethod` reports that `T` is of type `System.Text.TextReader`.

Again, `howToCastThis` is of a close-constructed type, therefore, so is the method you want.

Note: Although not the case here, a method in a close-constructed type can introduce additional type arguments so you still would have to call `MakeGenericMethod` to close-construct the method in that case.

Now, if I were to try to translate this to your situation, I'm guessing it would look something like this:

```
var predictMethod = predictionEngine.GetType().GetMethods()
    .Single(mi => mi.Name == "Predict");

float prediction = (float)predictMethod.Invoke(predictionEngine, new object[] { inputValue });
```

I'm not sure about the syntax in your pseudocode call to `Predict`.  I assumed that `inputValue` was the only parameter and `genericInputClass` was only there to indicate that it was a type argument in the close-constructed type.  If this was incorrect, you'll need to figure out what actually goes in that `object[]` argument.

Comment: At first I have to thank you for that answer and great explanation! Unfortunately I had no time today but I hope that I'll find the time to implement that finally tomorrow. The only thing I'm not totally sure about by now is how to handle the creation of that genericInputClass Instance inputValue. In fact the genericInputClass contains several fields I have to set before calling predict. But I know the field names at runtime only and have to do some mapping before. I'll comment again and accept the answer as soon as I found the time to implement that, I think I could solve it from here. Thx!

Comment: I just tried some stuff with that minimal example and got it working. `Activator.CreateInstance()` to create the instance, `inputValue.GetType().GetFields()` to get the classes fields and `field.SetMethod.Invoke(inputValue, new object[] {fields value})` to set a specific fields value should do it for now. THX for your help!

Comment: That's great news! I'm glad I could help.